# Why does getaddrinfo() return IPv4 address even thought I choose AF_INET6?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

This is the example code from MSDN.
I only changed `hints.ai_family` to `AF_INET6`.

```
int main()
{   
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    ptr = result;
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket;

    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When I check the address that is returned, `result->ai_addr` is a 4 byte hex number. How can I make it return an IPv6 address?

**EDIT:** Since I (too) think I may be missing some points, the image below shows what I think its IP address is.

[image]

Found the solution.

```
struct sockaddr_in6* ipv6_address = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&(result->ai_addr);
```

I was casting pointer address of ai_addr. After correcting it, i checked it with `inet_ntop` and now it works.

Comment: How do you know it's returning 8 bytes? (IPv4 would be 4 bytes.)

Comment: You can't determine anything by looking at the raw `sockaddr` structure. You are supposed to inspect `result->ai_addr->sa_family`, then cast to a pointer to structure appropriate for a given family (e.g. `sockaddr_in` for IPv4, `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you give a brief example code, please?(only casting part) I couldn't figure out how to cast those different structs.

Comment: `sockaddr_in* ipv4_address = (sockaddr_in*)(result->ai_addr);` Casting to `sockaddr_in6` is left as an exercise for the reader. Anyway - have you checked `result->ai_addr->sa_family`? What value does it have? Answering this question doesn't require casting.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik After casting, I still see 4 bytes of address. Maybe I am missing some point.

Comment: @ozgur Yes, you're looking at or diagnosing something wrong. We don't know what you're looking at, so that's hard to give advice about. Perhaps you're looking at the pointer itself, not what it points to.

Comment: @nos I added an image where I show what i am looking at. You may be right at this point.

Comment: @ozgur If you mean you look at the number 0x00938e6a , then yes, that's the pointer (the memory address where the socket address is stored, )which is't very interesting in itself. ai_family is 23, which is AF_INET6, and that means you have to cast ai_addr to a sockaddr_in6* to interpret it, and among other things, that sockaddr_in6 struct will contain the IPv6 address.

Comment: @nos **u = {Byte=0x00978d70 "" Word=0x00978d70 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} }** now this is what I see. after I cast it. I think i am a very tough student.

Comment: @ozgur Seems reasonable. It's binding to the IPv6 address 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00. Ofcourse the 0x00978d70 and 0x00978d70 are memory addresses, which are again not interesting in this case, you should be more interested in what those addresses/pointers point to. The debugger is also interpreting the Byte member(you're looking at this struct ) as a string which is why you see an empty string (the ""), which is quite unhelpful and unfortunate. But you can perhaps expand it to see the individual bytes.

Comment: @nos you were right all along. thank you.